# Не могу добиться исчезновения элемента при загрузке страницы!

Tags: javascript, html, css, opacity

[Пример уже существующего кода](http://studiobuettner.com/portfolio/bergen-assembly-2019/#!/19)

Не могу добиться исчезновения надписи при запуске страницы, по ссылке можете посмотреть существующий пример. При загрузке страницы надпись, находящаяся над другими элементами должна плавно исчезать за 2 секунды.

Заранее благодарю за ответы и помощь!

```css
.seriestitle {
  z-index: 998;
  position: absolute;
  left: 1rem;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: calc(100% - 2rem);
  top: 50%;
  text-align: center;
  transform: translate(0, -50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(0, -50%);
  -webkit-transform: translate(0, -50%);
  letter-spacing: -.03em;
}

.yellowFont {
  color: green;
  font-size: 2.8125rem;
  font-size: 9vw;
  line-height: 0.9375em;
  text-shadow: 0px 3px 6px rgba(10, 10, 10, 0.4);
}
```

```html
<div class="seriestitle yellowFont"> Example </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```css
.seriestitle {
  z-index: 998;
  position: absolute;
  left: 1rem;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: calc(100% - 2rem);
  top: 50%;
  text-align: center;
  transform: translate(0, -50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(0, -50%);
  -webkit-transform: translate(0, -50%);
  letter-spacing: -.03em;
  animation: dissapear 1s linear 1s 1 forwards;
}

.yellowFont {
  color: green;
  font-size: 2.8125rem;
  font-size: 9vw;
  line-height: 0.9375em;
  text-shadow: 0px 3px 6px rgba(10, 10, 10, 0.4);
}

@keyframes dissapear{
0%{
  opacity 1;
  visibility: visible;
}
 100%{
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
}
}
```

```html
<div class="seriestitle yellowFont"> Example </div>
```

Comment: Большое спасибо за ответ! Всё работает!

Answer (score 1):

Можно использовать `@keyframes` [почитайте](https://html5book.ru/css3-animation/)

```css
.seriestitle {
  z-index: 998;
  position: absolute;
  left: 1rem;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: calc(100% - 2rem);
  top: 50%;
  text-align: center;
  transform: translate(0, -50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(0, -50%);
  -webkit-transform: translate(0, -50%);
  letter-spacing: -.03em;
  animation: anime 2s ease-in-out forwards;
}

.yellowFont {
  color: green;
  font-size: 2.8125rem;
  font-size: 9vw;
  line-height: 0.9375em;
  text-shadow: 0px 3px 6px rgba(10, 10, 10, 0.4);
}

@keyframes anime {
  0%{
    opacity: 1;
    visibility: visible;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="seriestitle yellowFont"> Example </div>
```

Comment: Большое спасибо, всё работает!